# What is the proper way to standardize non-stationary data?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, standardization

I have a 19-year time series of satellite imagery (spaced irregularly temporally). The mean and standard deviation of the dataset changes over the 19 years.

I get multiple variables from each image; these are each set up in their own array. My ultimate goal is to run a multiple regression of these variables where the outputs are standardized beta coefficients.

I'm using the equation (as Matlab code):

*Standardize_Array  =   (   ARRAY_IMPERVIOUS -  nanmean(     ARRAY_IMPERVIOUS(:)))/(nanstd( ARRAY_IMPERVIOUS (:)))*

**My question is**: Should I standardize the *entire* array at once (that is, use the mean and standard deviation of the entire 19-year time series), or should I standardize each day independently? Since standardization just rescales the data, does it matter so long as I'm consistent?

Comment: You're proposing two entirely different approaches, so determining which is appropriate depends entirely on your goals and reasons for standardizing.

Comment: I am not sure if you are really concerned with stationarity or standardizing your data. They are very different issues. Beta weights depend on variation so if this changes over time significantly you would have to change the beta weights. Analyzing the data in different ranges (segments of time) where the variation does not change would seem a solution although that is an opinion as I have not seen this addressed. You might look at the literature of a chow test in this regard althugh that just identifies segments it does not deal with standardization.